# How to add a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there a straight forward way to add a list to a dictionary?

For example

```
a = [1,2,3]
d = dict(a)
```

I have seen a way (I do not remember exactly how) that add a list to a dictionary making the name of the list as key and list's values as values in the dictionary, something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
d = somefunction(a)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a':[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Does `dict(a=a)` work for you?

Comment: @nisemonoxide Exactly what I want, Thank you

Comment: Sure, anytime! You can find more information and examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).